# SELECT WHERE IN(subquery)

Tags: mysql

Is there any approach for something like this? :

```
SELECT * FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
    ON table1.field = table2.field
WHERE field2 IN (SELECT * FROM table3 WHERE field LIKE '%pattern%')
```

To be more precise , inside the IN() i need the values from rows of table3 that match a %pattern% so i can get the rows from the main query that have field2 IN() range of table3 values.

Answer (score 0):

You should select only needed field like

```
SELECT field2 FROM table3 WHERE field LIKE '%pattern%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do but the number and type of the columns must match

```
SELECT * FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.field = table2.field
WHERE field2 IN (SELECT field3 FROM table3 WHERE field LIKE '%pattern%')
```

or eg:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.field = table2.field
WHERE (field2_1, field2_2) fi IN (SELECT field3_1, field3_2
                                 FROM table3 
                                 WHERE field LIKE '%pattern%')
```

The (field2_1, field2_2) and  field3_1, field3_2  must match for number and type

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the sub-query , you can directly use the JOIN for table3:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 T1
INNER JOIN table2 T2 ON T2.field = T1.field
INNER JOIN table3 T3 ON T3.field = T1.field2
WHERE T3.field LIKE '%pattern%'
```

Here T1, T2 and T3 are [table alias](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp) for better readability